# Tkinter canvas animation

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I'm working with Tkinter and canvas, and I want to make a moving animation. I have a coordinate list:

```
# coordinates
x = [100, 200, 300, 400]
y = [50, 200, 250, 300]

# starting point
radius = 5
dot = canvas.create_oval(x[0]-radius, y[0]-radius, x[0]+radius, y[0]+radius, fill="red")
```

Expected output would be the animation of the "dot" moving like this:

```
# dot coordinates: 
# (100, 50) -> (200, 200) -> (300, 250) -> (400, 300) -> (300, 250) -> (200, 200) -> (100, 50) -> ...
```

Could you show me how can I make such animation in Tkinter?

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can use `canvas.coords(dot, ...)` to move the *"dot"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it with a combination of `canvas.coords(dot, ...)`, as @acw1668 suggests (+1), and tkinter's `after()` method:

```
import tkinter as tk
from itertools import cycle

RADIUS = 5
DELAY = 1000  # milliseconds
WIDTH, HEIGHT = 500, 500

coordinates = [(100, 50), (200, 200), (300, 250), (400, 300)]

def move():
    x, y = next(cycled_coordinates)
    canvas.coords(dot, x-RADIUS, y-RADIUS, x+RADIUS, y+RADIUS)
    canvas.after(DELAY, move)

cycled_coordinates = cycle(coordinates)

master = tk.Tk()

canvas = tk.Canvas(master, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT)
canvas.pack()

x, y = next(cycled_coordinates)

dot = canvas.create_oval(x-RADIUS, y-RADIUS, x+RADIUS, y+RADIUS, fill='red')

canvas.after(DELAY, move)

master.mainloop()
```